# Add http header forwarding traffic with netcat or socat

Tags: linux, http, networking, sed, netcat

There is any way to easy add an http header to traffic forwarded by netcat (or other) command line tool?

1. I’m doing forwarding with `ncat -lk localhost 1234 | ncat -v localhost 2345`
2. I try put a sed between but they doesn’t work as expected locking on the last message line (the payload)

Comment: The problem with `sed` may have been due to buffering. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258177/how-to-stop-sed-from-buffering

Comment: I already tried with the `-u` (unbuffered option) but the problem is the same because the payload not necessarily ends with a new line then the entire last line with the payload is not evaluated.

Comment: Yeah, you probably need to use something that operates on characters, not lines. The `sed2perl` answer might provide a starting point.

Comment: s2p works line by line

Comment: I know. But you can edit the resulting Perl code to process differently. That's why I said it's a "starting point".